# Why is the restoring force not zero at the equilibrium position of simple harmonic motion?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring, free-body-diagram, equilibrium

The restoring force is applied in order to take the body it's equilibrium.  Then in a SHM why in the mean position restoring force maximum rather than being zero as it has reached equilibrium. (After leaving it from maximum position)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is zero at the equilibrium position: the restoring force is $F = - k x$, where $x = 0$ at the equilibrium position.

Comment: In the case of, e.g.,  a [mass hanging from a spring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zU58M.png), the restoring force isn't zero at the equilibrium position.

Comment: @HalHollis Couldn't you argue it is $0$ if you say the restoring force is the combined force of the spring and gravity? Of course you can't say that force is proportional to the displacement, but it is still, overall, a restoring force, right?

Comment: @AaronStevens, that is argued [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/54924/140996)

Comment: @HalHollis Yeah, so it is basically just how you decide to define it. Kind of like how if you have an object on a string moving in a circle perpendicular to the ground. The tension is the centripetal force acting on the object to cause circular motion, but you could technically say gravity (or certain components at certain times) is also a centripetal force. It is not a perfect analogy, but I think it helps.

Comment: @AaronStevens, I suppose my first comment could be clarified as so:  *In the case of, e.g., a mass hanging from a spring, the restoring force (of the spring) isn't zero at the equilibrium position.*

Comment: @HalHollis Yes, I agree :)

Answer (score 2):

The restoring force is zero, it is the inertia of the object that keeps it from stopping at that point.
Once the object crosses the equilibrium point, the restoring force starts acting on it again, but this time in the opposite direction.