# If force by block on spring and restoring force are action reaction, why does spring restoring exist when block is removed?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram, spring, interactions

Imagine a scene when a massless spring of spring constant(100N/m) is connected to 2 blocks of mass $M$ being pulled by 100N each.
(All surfaces are frictionless.)

[image]

by N3L,block also pull external agent by 100N,and since 100N force is acting on block,blocks would move away from spring,therefore applying a pulling force on the part of the spring from where they are connected,and by N3L,spring would apply a reaction force on the blocks,which is called spring restoring force

[image]

At Equilibrium,this is the situation

Now I have 2 doubts:

1. How are the pulling force by block on spring and spring restoring force action reaction pair? imagine at equilibrium, I disconnect the masses from the springs, therefore the masses would no longer exert the action pull force on spring,and therefore, the reaction force should also vanish, but we know the reaction force,the spring restoring force, does exist, and it will pull the end of the springs back and the spring would then oscillate

So,even after removal of action force (force by mass on spring), the reaction force(spring restoring force) existed, indicating that spring restoring force and force by mass on block are not action reaction

[image]

But one interesting thing here is that the spring restoring force pulls the end of the spring towards itself, means, THAT NOW THE SPRING RESTORING FORCE ACTS ON THE END OF THE SPRING, but earlier it was acting on the mass $M$, so, where actually does the spring restoring force act? Does it pull the end of the spring or the block? if it pulls the spring, then spring restoring force is not the reaction force of blocks pull force on spring, then what's the reaction force? And if spring restoring force is indeed the reaction force to blocks pull force on spring, why then, after removal of interaction of block and spring, does spring restoring force still exist, and why the spring restoring force starts acting on the end part of the spring? Instead of the block? How can spring restoring force act on 2 parts?

Comment: Can we assume the blocks are on top of a frictionless surface?

Comment: Yes!sorry for not mentioning it

Comment: Also, regarding the second diagram, you don't add the two 100N forces to determine the displacement.  The tension in the spring is 100N not 200N. Therefore the displacement is 1 meter not two.

Comment: I'm going to submit an answer.

Comment: I have updated my answer. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Before analyzing any problem like this it is helpful to start with accurate free body diagrams so that one can properly identify the so called "action-reaction" forces, i.e., the force pairs governed by Newton's 3rd law, and those that are not. The action-reaction pairs are generally considered to be *internal* forces on a system depending on how it's defined, i.e., forces that do not result in linear or angular acceleration of a rigid body.

FIG 1 below is a free body diagram (FBD) of the entire spring mass system. The only external forces acting on the system are the equal and opposite 100N forces. Per Newtons 2nd Law (N2L) the net force on the system is zero and it therefore does not accelerate.

FIG 2 are FBD's for each mass and the spring. The external forces acting on each are identified as N2L.  They determine whether or not each body accelerates. Note that the sum of the external forces acting on each body is zero, for equilibrium. The internal equal and opposite forces per Newton's 3rd law are identified as N3L. They don't effect the equilibrium of the three bodies.

FIG 3 cuts the spring into two sections to shown that the tension, and thus restoring force, exists throughout the spring.

> Imagine a scene when a massless spring of spring constant(100N/m) is
> connected to 2 blocks of mass $M$ being pulled by 100N each. (All
> surfaces are frictionless.) By N3L,block also pull external agent by
> 100N…

In order to show the action-reaction pair between the blocks and the externally applied forces as internal forces,  it is necessary to expand the system to include the sources of the external forces on the blocks.

> ……Imagine at equilibrium, I disconnect the masses from the springs,
> therefore the masses would no longer exert the action pull force on
> spring and therefore, the reaction force should also vanish, but we
> know the reaction force, the spring restoring force, does exist…

The action-reaction force pairs between the blocks and the spring only exist when the blocks are connected to the spring. Once disconnected, all the forces on the spring are internal between adjacent elements of the spring.

> …and it will pull the end of the springs back and the spring would
> then oscillate

If you are going to consider the behavior of the spring after severing it from the blocks, then you must consider a spring having mass.  A massless spring cannot have kinetic energy.

Incidentally, your second diagram appears to indicate the spring extends 2m, as if you are adding the two 100N forces. The extension depends on the 100N force and spring constant. So the total displacement should be 1m not 2m.

Also, you show $F=F’=100N$ by N2L. You need to consider $F=F'$ separately from $F'=100N$ to identify the application of N2L and N3L.  $F=F’$ is based on N3L and $F=100N$ is based on N2L for equilibrium of the block on the left side.  Similarly, on the right side $F_{1}’=F_{1}$ is based on N3L and $F_{1}=100N$ is based on N2L for equilibrium of the block on the right.

> But one interesting thing here is that the spring restoring force
> pulls the end of the spring towards itself, means, THAT NOW THE SPRING
> RESTORING FORCE ACTS ON THE END OF THE SPRING

No, the spring restoring force is not only at the end of the spring. It acts everywhere in the spring. It is the result of the electrostatic attraction forces between all the atoms of the spring material and creates the tension in the spring. It exists in every section of the spring. See FIG 3 where the spring is cut into two equal sections. The same result exists no matter how many sections it is cut into. The six questions that follow are all related to this basic misunderstanding of what’s going on in the spring.

Hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: which one of the forces in the 2nd diagram is the spring restoring force???

Comment: @Aakash the “spring restoring force” isn’t a thing. It doesn’t exist as a separate force. The only forces are the “external agent” forces and the tension forces. That is the point of writing good free body diagrams.

Comment: @Aakash As Dale pointed out, a "restoring force" doesn't exist as a separate force. It's a name that can apply to any force that acts in a direction to restore equilibrium.  David Z, I think, sums it up pretty well in his answer here:https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/54924/is-restoring-force-a-particular-type-of-force#:~:text=That's%20right.,the%20system%20back%20into%20equilibrium.

Comment: That said, the 100 N forces acting on the masses in the direction of the spring would restore the spring to its original equilibrium length, were it not for the external 100N forces acting outward on the masses. Note,  however, that in FIG 1 these forces are internal forces (not shown)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're getting confused by the concept of discrete components (a mass that's rigid enough to ignore its own deformation, a spring that's light enough to ignore its own weight, with forces acting only on the boundaries and nothing important happening inside the components). These are idealizations.

All the objects you draw have springiness and mass, including every internal section of the spring. The springiness arises to some degree from stretched bonds within the material. (The special case of the ideal elastomer, whose springiness is solely entropic, is ignored here for simplicity.)

You can isolate any section of the spring and consider the forces acting on it (and then determine its acceleration, stress state, and deformation). The restoring force you describe isn't something that acts solely at the end of a lumped component; it acts everywhere within the spring.

Put another way, the springiness of one part of the spring can act on the mass of another part of the spring, accelerating and deforming it. It's not as if there's a single restoring force that can act only at the boundaries of these defined components; real objects contain a continuum of matter. If you've come to the limit of usefulness or clarity with the idealization of discrete components, start thinking in terms of the continuum of atoms and molecules.

Answer (score 0):

> How are the pulling force by block on spring and spring restoring
> force action reaction pair?

They aren't. Third law pairs are *always* equal and opposite. Note that you can pull the block harder than the spring pulls back - it's clearly possible to move the block to the right with a sufficient pull, in which case the pulling force exceeds the spring restoring force. Conversely, if you stop pulling, the spring force clearly exceeds the pulling force and the spring contracts.

There's no requirement for these forces to be equal in magnitude, therefore, they are not a third law pair. The forces happen to be in balance in an equilibrium position, but Newton's third law applies whether you are in equilibrium or not. If you can identify even a single instance where a pair of force are not equal and opposite, they cannot be a third law pair.

Comment: So what are the third law pair to the spring restoring force and the blocks pulling force?

Comment: @Aakash The restoring force pulling at one end of the spring is always equal and opposite to the restoring force pulling at the other end of the spring - both ends of the spring are always pulled toward the center equally (much like a tension force). The force of you pulling on the block is equal and opposite to the force the block exerts on you - when you pull the block toward you, the block is also pulling you toward it.

Comment: The reaction force of the block pulling the end of the spring??

Comment: @Aakash There has to be another part of the system not pictured that is imparting the pulling force to the block. The block itself isn't doing the pulling.

Comment: Yeah some external agent pulls the block,the block also pulls the external agent,the block moves to right due to pull of external agent,since block is connected to the end of the spring,it pulls the end of the spring as it moves to the right,what's the reaction force of this pull of the spring by the block to the right???

Comment: I think ur confused,I was talking about wheter the force by which THE BLOCK pulls the spring and the spring restoring force are action reaction pair or not??

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you release the 100 N external force, the spring restoring force is still 100 N, but it is unbalanced.  The Newton's 2nd Law equation on a single block goes from:

$$F_{ext}-F_{spring}=(100 \,\mathrm{N})-(100 \,\mathrm{N}) = ma = 0$$

to:

$$F_{ext}-F_{spring}=(0)-(100 \,\,\mathrm{N}) = ma = -100 \,\mathrm{N}$$

You've gone from a statics problem to a dynamics problem.  The mass will accelerate and then later oscillate as the spring force will change with position.

Comment: My question isn't about Newton 2nd law,it's about,when I release the "FORCE BY WHICH THE BLOCK PULLS THE SPRING",(please read again)," FORCE BY WHICH THE SPRING PULLS THE BLOCK,that is SPRING RESTORING FORCE "should also vanish,but we see that the end of the spring is pulled by spring restoring force, why does that still exist????

Comment: No need to get excited. What you are saying is the same as saying there is a weight hanging from a chain suspended from the ceiling, which you are raising by pulling the chain downward over a pulley. Then one link in the chain breaks. The weight of the object is still there, and pulls the chain upward and over the pulley.